# Another way for calling a get method

Tags: jquery

Is there another way to get a function from another page, that contains a variable being passed? My code:

```
    function getvoucher(id){

$.get("http://inactive/test.php?id=" + id, function(data, status){
return data;
});
}
```

However, the console tells me that my get method is wrong, is there another way I could do this? I receive what is in the page is just does not display, all I get is a blank page.

Comment: What is the actual error message?

Comment: It gets the id from the other page but doesn't display it on the current page

Comment: Your code syntax is incorrect. 1. Closing parenthesis is missing in .get, 2. Closing curly braces is missing in your callback method.

Comment: @BonMacalindong ok can you check it out now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

better you make your ajax request with `.done` event

```
   var url="http://inactive/test.php?id=" + id;
   $.get( url)
      .done(function( data ) {
        alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
   });
```